# keyframes animation not working in ie11 after ajax call, works fine in ie10

Tags: animation, internet-explorer-11

I've been fighting with this issue all morning:
I have a simple keyframes animation that works fine in chrome, safari, firefox and ie10, but with ie11 it doesn't work, or at least not after an ajax call.
The animation works perfectly if I place it in the main body of the page, but stops working if  I place it in the returned html of an ajax call. here's my code:

```
<div class="ie-animation-test">
    test
</div>


.ie-animation-test {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999999999;
  animation: 3s infinite ie-anim-test ;
}

@keyframes ie-anim-test {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  50% {
    top: 200px;
    left: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 400px;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?????????

Comment: I can't remember, sorry. Maybe if you force the element to be redrawn it will start the animation: try setting it to display: none; after the ajax, then use a setTimeout to wait a couple of milliseconds and then set it back to display: block.

Comment: Thanks @JonasGrumann I switched my JQuery insert function from html() to append() and it worked

Comment: Nice, I'm glad you figured it out :)

Comment: Scrap that... doesn't work in IE11 Windows 10 :(

Comment: :(((( I'm sorry I can't help you further, I even changed job so I don't have access to the project where I had the problem

Comment: I had `backface-visibility: hidden;` needed to be `visible` :)

Comment: Well :) again then xD